# Added interaction terms to logistic regression - how to interpret from here?

Tags: regression, logistic, interaction

I'm using logistic regression in r to examine correlates of experiencing headache (yes(1)/no (0)) when taking a medication. My correlates (all categorical) include:

- number of tablets of the medication (tabs)
- year
- gender
- age
- health district (HD)
- location (home, work, outside)

I have two interaction terms that seem to be significant - Health district (HD) x year, and HD x # of tablets

I ran the model with the interaction terms (see below), and I'm just not sure where to go from here. I know that for the variables involved in the interaction, I can't interpret the ORs as I normally would. Instead, I plotted the tabs by health district and year.. is that enough? When showing my regression table, should I show **all** of the ORs, but only interpret the ones not involved in interaction?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Here are the regression results with coefficients exponentiated:

```
                               exp(Est.) 2.5%   97.5%    P
(Intercept)                         0.20 0.01    4.17 0.30
tabs2                               2.15 0.36   12.82 0.40
tabs3                               0.70 0.05    9.37 0.79
tabs>3                              6.66 0.70   63.57 0.10
year2016                            0.17 0.01    4.57 0.29
year2017                            0.08 0.00    1.35 0.08
year2018                            0.06 0.00    1.18 0.06
genderFemale                        0.80 0.57    1.11 0.19
genderOther                         0.00 0.00     Inf 0.99
genderUnknown                       1.16 0.58    2.32 0.67
age19 - 30                          2.88 0.65   12.73 0.16
age31 - 60                          3.22 0.73   14.10 0.12
ageOver 60                          1.57 0.23   10.71 0.65
ageUnknown                          2.48 0.53   11.67 0.25
HDVIHA                              0.11 0.00    3.11 0.19
HDFHA                               0.42 0.03    6.81 0.54
HDIHA                               0.49 0.03    8.02 0.61
HDVCH                               0.11 0.01    2.12 0.14
HDUnknown                           2.36 0.30   18.52 0.41
locationhome                        0.63 0.45    0.90 0.01
locationwork                        0.67 0.36    1.26 0.21
locationOther                       0.57 0.39    0.83 0.00
tabs2:HDVIHA                        0.52 0.05    5.19 0.58
tabs3:HDVIHA                        0.60 0.02   19.77 0.77
tabs>3:HDVIHA                       0.00 0.00     Inf 0.98
tabs2:HDFHA                         0.78 0.12    5.20 0.80
tabs3:HDFHA                         1.68 0.11   24.87 0.71
tabs>3:HDFHA                        0.27 0.02    3.21 0.30
tabs2:HDIHA                         0.44 0.06    3.40 0.43
tabs3:HDIHA                         6.12 0.38   97.95 0.20
tabs>3:HDIHA                        0.69 0.06    8.68 0.78
tabs2:HDVCH                         0.26 0.03    2.21 0.21
tabs3:HDVCH                         0.64 0.03   13.12 0.77
tabs>3:HDVCH                        0.45 0.03    6.41 0.55
tabs2:HDUnknown                     0.61 0.09    4.19 0.62
tabs3:HDUnknown                     3.36 0.23   49.51 0.38
tabs>3:HDUnknown                    0.40 0.04    4.52 0.46
year2016:HAVIHA                    51.05 0.88 2966.51 0.06
year2017:HDVIHA                    48.41 1.23 1913.35 0.04
year2018:HDVIHA                     0.00 0.00     Inf 0.99
year2016:HDFHA                      3.26 0.10  104.55 0.50
year2017:HDFHA                      5.80 0.30  111.77 0.24
year2018:HDFHA                      7.48 0.32  174.24 0.21
year2016:HDIHA                      4.34 0.13  148.79 0.42
year2017:HDIHA                      8.45 0.40  177.91 0.17
year2018:HDIHA                      6.23 0.25  153.68 0.26
year2016:HDVCH                     36.08 0.97 1336.63 0.05
year2017:HDVCH                     81.30 3.04 2173.58 0.01
year2018:HDVCH                     32.33 0.93 1123.52 0.05
year2016:HDUnknown                  0.00 0.00     Inf 0.98
year2017:HDUnknown                  2.35 0.48   11.49 0.29
year2018:HDUnknown                  1.00 1.00    1.00  NaN
```

Comment: That's a lot of potential predictors; I count 50 including all the interaction terms. When you do 50 significance tests there's a good chance that 2 or 3 tests will appear to be "significant" just by chance. How many cases do you have for each of the headache and no-headache categories? That's important to know in terms of framing a helpful answer.

Comment: @EdM Thank you! I have 1772 'no headache' cases and 255 'headache' cases!

Answer (score 4):

The usual rule of thumb to avoid overfitting in logistic regression is to have about 15 cases in the minority class per predictor you are evaluating, unless you are using some type of penalization like with ridge regression. That's about 17 total predictors including interactions for your data set with 255 headache cases. Your model, with 3 times that many predictors, is probably very badly overfit and the p-values are unreliable.

To cut down on the number of predictors, try to use variables like `age` and `year` as continuous rather than categorical predictors. Consider modeling the health districts `HD` as random effects in a [mixed model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/mixed-model/info) instead of fixed effects.

Instead of setting aside separate "unknown" categories, use multiple imputation to get multiple complete data sets with the missing data estimated in a principled way. Besides cutting down several categories, that avoids bias resulting from the "missingness" pattern and lets you get estimates that take the variability both in the model and in the data imputation into account.

The situation you face is very common in biomedical studies. See Frank Harrell's [course notes](http://hbiostat.org/doc/rms.pdf) and [book](http://hbiostat.org/rms/) on Regression Modeling Strategies. Besides what Harrell has to say about data imputation, Stef van Buuren has a helpful and freely available [book](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/) specifically on that topic.

It's worth your while to analyze your data well. Take advantage of this as an opportunity to learn more about this type of modeling, if possible collaborating with an experienced statistician.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply! I had previously tried to do multiple imputation, but we weren't sure how reliable it was for this dataset. I tried transforming the medication tabs and year into numeric variables. When I do that, my interaction term between year and health district becomes insignificant. Is that normal, and can in this case can I proceed without that interaction term?

Comment: @amb that can happen. An interaction that is "statistically insignificant" isn't necessarily unimportant to the model. Search this site for ["drop insignificant interaction"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=drop+insignificant+interaction) for discussion about why it's often best to keep it in. Also, be careful in how you evaluate the significance of the interaction term. Many individual year:district interactions above had p<0.05 but it's not clear that the interaction overall was significant. For that, do anova comparing nested models with and without the interaction term.